# Adding watermark directly to the stream

Tags: java, itext, watermark

> I am creating a PDF on Servletoutputstream.
>   I need to add watermark directly to the stream before exporting it to PDF.
>   Is there any solution to add watermark on fly without having saved PDF or to get the document object from the stream.

Comment: As @injecteer's answer already indicates, you can pipe the PDF which you currently stream as response, into a `PdfReader` instead, watermark using a `PdfStamper`, and send the result of that stamping as response. This been said, though, considering resource usage it would be better to add the watermark already while creating the original PDF.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by *@injecteer* is correct (apart from the fact that he uses `com.lowagie` classes which tells me he is using [an obsolete version of iText)](http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq), but he suggests creating the final PDF in two passes. First the PDF is created without a watermark, then it's created with a watermark.

As *@mkl* indicates in his comment, you can create the PDF in one go if you use page events. I've written a small [Watermarking](https://web.archive.org/web/20151023054638/http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/events/Watermarking) example.

This is the page event class:

```
public class Watermark extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    protected Phrase watermark = new Phrase("WATERMARK", new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 60, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY));

    @Override
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContentUnder();
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, watermark, 298, 421, 45);
    }
}
```

This event is added to the `PdfWriter` like this:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
writer.setPageEvent(new Watermark());
```

From now on, the text defined in the `Watermark` event class will be added under the existing content every time a page is completed.

Comment: Sir, how to get document object for Servletoutputstream. Using ireport i am creating pdf on stream, in the same pdf before exporting it to pdf file, i need to add watermark through itext.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The question "How to get the `Document` object for `ServletOutputStream`" sounds very awkward. You're suddenly introducing iReport (probably making it a JasperReports question, rather than an iText question). As for adding a watermark through iText: you have two answer (mine and injecteers) explaining you EXACTLY how to do it. I don't know what more info an experience developer would need.

Comment: Sir, i am very new in development..In my project i am creating report using JasperReports and using Itext to add watermark in same report. Here i have to write two separate actions for making the pdf one for using the template of JasperReport and then another for using that pdf file generated and making watermark in it. So i need to add watermark directly on this template rather than passing any existing Pdf.

Comment: Bruno's answer should be the accepted answer. I tried for a long time to implement with Input and Output ByteArrays as per Injecteer with no joy. The class Override of onEndPage worked first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PdfStamper` for that. The following piece of groovy code adds an Image on each page "on the fly" and writes the resulting PDF directly into `out`:

```
  import com.lowagie.text.pdf.*

  void addWM( ByteArrayOutputStream baos, com.itextpdf.text.Image image, out ){
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader( baos.toByteArray() )
    PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper( reader, out, reader.pdfVersion )

    try{
      ( 1..reader.numberOfPages ).each{ int page ->
        PdfContentByte over = stamp.getOverContent( page )
        over.beginText()
                    addImage()
        over.endText()
      }
    }finally{
      stamp.close()
      baos.close()
    }
  }
```