# iText add Watermark to selected pages

Tags: java, itext

I need to add a watermark to every page that has certain text, such as "PROCEDURE DELETED".

Based on Bruno Lowagie's suggestion in [Adding watermark directly to the stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575630/adding-watermark-directly-to-the-stream/21577767#comment44808982_21577767)

So far have the PdfWatermark Class with:

```
protected Phrase watermark = new Phrase("DELETED", new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 60, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.PINK));
ArrayList<Integer> arrPages = new ArrayList<Integer>();
boolean pdfChecked = false;

@Override
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {

    if(pdfChecked == false) {
        detectPages(writer, document);
        pdfChecked = true;
    } 
    int pageNum = writer.getPageNumber();

    if(arrPages.contains(pageNum)) {
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContentUnder();
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, watermark, 298, 421, 45);
    }
}
```

And this works fine if I add, say, the number 3 to the arrPages ArrayList in my custom detectPages method - it shows the desired watermark on page 3.

What I am having trouble with is how to search through the document for the text string, which I have access to here, only from the PdfWriter writer or the com.itextpdf.text.Document document sent to onEndPage method.

Here is what I have tried, unsuccessfully:

```
 private void detectPages(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    try {

        //arrPages.add(3);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, byteArrayOutputStream);
        //following code no work
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(writer.getDirectContent().getPdfDocument());
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
        PdfImportedPage page;

        for (int i = 0; i < reader.getNumberOfPages(); ) {    
            page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, ++i);
            canvas.addTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0.4f, 0.4f, 72, 50 * i);
            canvas.beginText();
            canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER,

                    //search String
                    String.valueOf((char)(181 + i)), 496, 150 + 50 * i, 0);

                    //if(detected) arrPages.add(i);

            canvas.endText();
        }
```

Am I on the right track with this as a solution or do I need to back out?

Can anyone supply the missing link needed to scan the doc and pick out "PROCEDURE DELETED" pages?

EDIT: I am using iText 5.0.4 - cannot upgrade to 5.5.X at this time, but could probably upgrade to latest version below that.

EDIT2: More information: This is approach to adding text to the document (`doc`):

```
        String processed = processText(template);
        List<Element> objects = HTMLWorker.parseToListLog(new StringReader(processed),
                styles, interfaceProps, errors);
        for (Element elem : objects) {
            doc.add(elem);

        }
```

That is called in an `addText` method I control. The `template` is simply html from a database LOB. The `processText` checks the html for custom markers contained by curlies as in `${replaceMe}`.

This seems to be the place to identify the "PROCEDURE DELETED" string during generation of the document, but I don't see the path to Chunk.setGenericTags().

EDIT3: Table difficulties

```
        List<Element> objects = HTMLWorker.parseToListLog(new StringReader(processed),
                styles, interfaceProps, errors);
        for (Element elem : objects) { 
            //Code below no work
            if (elem instanceof PdfPTable) {
                PdfPTable table = (PdfPTable) elem;
                ArrayList<Chunk> chks = table.getChunks();
                for(Chunk chk : chks){
                    if(chk.toString().contains("TEST DELETED")) {
                        chk.setGenericTag("delete_tag");
                    }
                }                       
            }

            doc.add(elem);
        }
```

Commenters mlk and Bruno suggested to detect the "PROCEDURE DELETED" keywords at the time they are added to the doc. However, since the keywords are necessarily inside a table, they have to be detected through PdfPTable rather than the simpler Element.

I could not do it with the code above. Any suggestions exactly how to find text inside a table cell and do a string comparison on it?

EDIT4: Based on some experimentation, I would like to make some assertions and please show me the way through them:

1. Using `Chunk.setGenericTag()` is required to trigger the handler `onGenericTag`
2. For some reason `(PdfPTable) table.getChunks()` does not return chunks, at least that my system picks up. This is counterintuitive and possibly there is a setup, version, or code bug causing this behavior.
3. Therefore, a selection text string inside a table cannot be used to trigger a watermark.

Comment: You are on the wrong track. The code in your second snippet is wrong on many levels. Before anyone can answer your question, you'll have to tell us if you're creating a document from scratch (it looks that way since you're using page events), or if you're working with an existing PDF (the fact that you use `PdfReader` indicates that you might be.

Comment: The document is being dynamically created. It will not be saved to a file until it is complete, with watermarks. The second snippet is just what I could find as example for getting the page number, getting the page content, and finding a character sequence to control the watermarking.

Comment: Why are you first adding the character sequence to a page and then afterwards trying to retrieve that character sequence from the content of a page? Why don't you mark the character sequence with a generic tag, and then use a page event to determine if the watermark needs to be added or not?

Comment: *iText 5.0.4 - cannot upgrade to iText2 at this time* - what iText2 do you want to upgrade to from iText version 5.x?

Comment: @mkl - My EDIT 1 comment was wrong - I meant rewrite code to iText 5.5 specs (XmlWorker vs. HtmlWorker). I could upgrade the older iText to latest/last prior to that (5.4?) if I need something in them. Bruno - see EDIT 2 which explains why I am starting on the wrong end of things.

Comment: If I were to implement that, I'd check in your `for`-loop whether I can identify the element with the "PROCEDURE DELETED" string. If that proves possible, I'd add a flag to my page event listener; I'd set this flag in the loop whenever I identify the string, and in the listener I'd add header and footer and reset the flag if and only if the flag is set, As @Bruno explained, trying to search the PDF contents is a bad idea in this context.

Comment: When @mkl mentions *element*, you can interpret this in two ways: (1) an element in the HTML that you mark and for which you tweak the `TagFactory`, or (2) you parse the HTML into an `ElementList` and then inspect the elements for `PROCEDURE DELETED`. When such an element is detected, add a generic tag.

Comment: @mlk and Bruno - please see EDIT3. The info is embedded in an html table and that appears to complicate finding the text - but I am sure you can tell me the correction needed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all the help from @mkl and @Bruno, I finally got a workable solution. Anybody interested who can give a more elegant approach is welcome - there is certainly room.

Two classes were in play in all the snippets given in the original question. Below is partial code that embodies the working solution.

```
public class PdfExporter
    //a custom class to build content

    //create some content to add to pdf
    String text = "<div>Lots of important content here</div>";

    //assume the section is known to be deleted
    if(section_deleted) {
        //add a special marker to the text, in white-on-white
        text = "<span style=\"color:white;\">.!^DEL^?.</span>" + text + "</span>";
    } 

    //based on some indicator, we know we want to force a new page for a new section
    boolean ensureNewPage = true;

    //use an instance of PdfDocHandler to add the content
    pdfDocHandler.addText(text, ensureNewPage); 




public class PdfDocHandler extends PdfPageEventHelper
    private boolean isDEL;

    public boolean addText(String text, boolean ensureNewPage)

       if (ensureNewPage) {     
           //turn isDEL off: a forced pagebreak indicates a new section
           isDEL = false;
       }

        //attempt to find the special DELETE marker in first chunk
        //NOTE: this can be done several ways
        ArrayList<Chunk> chks = elem.getChunks();
        if(chks.size()>0) {
            if(chks.get(0).getContent().contains(".!^DEL^?.")) {
                //special delete marker found in text
                isDEL = true;
            }
        }

        //doc is an iText Document
        doc.add(elem);


    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {

        if(isDEL) {
            //set the watermark
            Phrase watermark = new Phrase("DELETED", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 60, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.PINK));
            PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContentUnder();
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, watermark, 298, 421, 45);   
        }
    }
```